# ios swift parse: How to handle error codes

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

While on a signup process, the user can cause several errors like
Username already taken, invalid email address etc...

Parse returns within the error object all needed infos see http://parse.com/docs/dotnet/api/html/T_Parse_ParseException_ErrorCode.htm

What I can't find out is how to use them eg how to access them in order to write a switch to catch all possibilities:

```
                user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
                    (succeeded: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {
                        // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
                        self.updateLabel("Erfolgreich registriert")
                    } else {
                        println(error.userInfo)
                    }
                }
```

What can I do to switch through the possible error code numbers?
Please advice
Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An `NSError` also has a property called [`code`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSError_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSError/code). That code contains the error-code you need. So you can make a switch-statement with that code:

```
user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (succeeded: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
        self.updateLabel("Erfolgreich registriert")
    } else {
        println(error.userInfo)
        var errorCode = error.code

        switch errorCode {
        case 100:
            println("ConnectionFailed")
            break
        case 101:
            println("ObjectNotFound")
            break
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to use the constants?  I really don't like hard-coding values...

Comment: @TakeshiKaga Yes you can, for instance: `case NSURLErrorCannotConnectToHost:`

Answer (score 2):

Hi i would do something like

```
if let error = error,let code = PFErrorCode(rawValue: error._code) {
    switch code {
    case .errorConnectionFailed:
        print("errorConnectionFailed")
    case .errorObjectNotFound:
        print("errorObjectNotFound")
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

You have the whole errors list there : https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/blob/master/Parse/PFConstants.h#L128

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `PFErrorCode`:

```
user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (succeeded: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
        self.updateLabel("Erfolgreich registriert")
    } else {
        println(error.userInfo)
        var errorCode = error!.code

        switch errorCode {
           case PFErrorCode.ErrorConnectionFailed.rawValue:
              println("ConnectionFailed")
           case PFErrorCode.ErrorObjectNotFound.rawValue:
              println("ObjectNotFound")
           default:
              break
        }
    }
}
```